# XMonad: How to write functions involving the `Query` datatype?

Tags: haskell, xmonad, xmonad-contrib

### Problem

I have a feeling that the reason for this question is going to ultimately come down to me just being new at/not understanding Haskell, so I'll try to be as detailed as I can with my description, to make it somewhat generic.

I am using a custom XMonad config as my window manager, defined in a file `xmonad.hs`.

The XMonad `manageHook` is what I use to handle when certain applications need to open in a certain type of window or on a certain workspace, etc.
https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-0.17.0/docs/XMonad-ManageHook.html

Currently, a bunch of lines in my `manageHook` in `xmonad.hs` look like this:

```
className =? "xxxx" --> doSomething
```

Here is my current understanding of the line above:

These expressions involve the value of `className`, defined in `XMonad.Hooks.ManageHook`, which is of the `Query` type (`Query [Char]`, to be more specific).
https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-0.17.0/docs/XMonad-ManageHook.html

`Query` is defined in `XMonad.Core`. https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-0.17.0/docs/XMonad-Core.html#t:Query

`=?` takes the `Query [Char]` on the left and the `[Char]` literal on the right and returns a value of type `Query Bool`; the value will be `True` if the `[Char]`s are equal and `False` otherwise (I think?)

`-->` takes the `Query Bool` on the left and an action on the right and executes the action if the value of the `Query Bool` is `True`.

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-0.17.0/docs/XMonad-ManageHook.html

However, this is only useful to me when I know the exact class name of an application I want to apply a rule to, which is not always the case. So, I took a look at xmonad-contrib to get some ideas as to what other functions I could define.

In `XMonad.Hooks.ManageHelpers` (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.17.0/docs/XMonad-Hooks-ManageHelpers.html), there is `^?`, which would be used like below:

```
className ^? "xxxx" --> doSomething
```

From my understanding, `^?` takes the `Query [Char]` on the left and the `[Char]` literal on the right and returns a value type of `Query Bool`; the value will be `True` if the `[Char]` on the left `isPrefixOf` the `[Char]` on the right and `False` otherwise (I think?)

What I would like to create is a new function that is similar, but reversed. Something like,

```
"xxxx" ?^ className --> doSomething
```

where `?^` takes the `[Char]` literal on the left and the `Query [Char]` on the right and returns a value of type `Query Bool`; the value should be `True` if the `[Char]` on the left `isPrefixOf` the `[Char]` on the right and `False` otherwise.
(In other words, I want to define a new function that checks if some string literal is a prefix of the class name, rather than checking if the class name is a prefix of some string literal.)

Initially, I thought this should be easy, but looking at the source code for `^?`, I realized there must be something I am fundamentally missing about my understanding of Haskell.

Here is the definition of `^?`:

```
(^?) :: (Eq a, Functor m) => m [a] -> [a] -> m Bool
q ^? x = fmap (`isPrefixOf` x) q
```

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.17.0/docs/src/XMonad.Hooks.ManageHelpers.html#%5E%3F

What I do not understand is how I would write a function that is a reversed version of this. This definitely won't work:

```
(?^) :: (Eq a, Functor m) => [a] -> m [a] -> m Bool
x ?^ q = fmap (`isPrefixOf` q) q
```

yet I do not understand why. What property does `Query` have that `(Query [a]) isPrefixOf ([a])` is acceptable, but not `([a]) isPrefixOf (Query [a])`?

Furthermore, how can I go about defining a function with the desired behavior? I am still pretty new to Haskell, so I do not know where to start.

### Solution

I was closer than I thought. See the answer for more details, but the solution was just to fix my syntax for the invocation of `isPrefixOf` (oops):

```
x ?^ q = fmap (x `isPrefixOf`) q
```

Comment: Neither ```(undefined :: Query [A]) `isPrefixOf` (undefined :: [A])``` nor ```(undefined :: [A]) `isPrefixOf` (undefined :: Query [A])``` is acceptable! The `fmap` changes everything; it takes a non-`Query` function and lifts it into `Query`-land, having type `fmap :: (a -> b) -> Query a -> Query b`.

Comment: @DanielWagner Thanks for the clarification! The issue with my code ended up being unrelated to `fmap`, but I'm glad I understand the function better now, because it is a large part of what was confusing me; I see it used frequently in Haskell code, but I never properly understood when it is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gotta switch the arguments to `isPrefixOf`!

```
x ?^ q = fmap (x `isPrefixOf`) q
```

Other spellings are possible, such as this version that doesn't use the infix form of `isPrefixOf`:

```
x ^? q = isPrefixOf x <$> q
```

(`(<$>)` is another name for `fmap`.)

Comment: Thanks! It was as simple as this. I think I was confused by the infix notation, but I thought something else was going on instead with `fmap` that was preventing it from working